# InvalidClassException in a non edited class

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

I'm getting this error :

```
ERROR com.calyon.espm.businessdelegate.translation.InCacheTranslationDelegateImpl 36  - 
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: 
Cannot access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://[url]/reference.espmservice]; 
nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: 
org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException; 
local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = -8541954612511556316
....
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = -8541954612511556316
```

How does it come I get such error since the class **InCacheTranslationDelegateImpl** have not been recently edited ?

Comment: It's only a hint but your exception seems to be the result of a configuration problem. The main error is "Cannot access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://[url]/reference.espmservice]; " where "url" is missinng. Can you check if this message is substituting the real url? If so your configuration is missing that url, the delegate can't open http connection etc.

Comment: You're actually right... It was a network problem. :)

Comment: No problem. Often it only needs four eyes to see the truth.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a network problem :)